# ht access mod rewrite, how to remove part of the url after another rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, web-deployment

i have a laravel site with the following htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The rule removes the 'public' part of the url and it results in :
http://example.com/rijopleidingen/brommobiel-opleidingen/praktijk-brommobiel

Now i need a new rule to remove the "rijopleidingen/" part of the url so that it will result into:
http://example.com/brommobiel-opleidingen/praktijk-brommobiel

The rule that removes 'public' always needs to be executed, the removing of 'rijopleidingen' only when it is present in the url.
I've searched online, but i cant seem to find the right rules that work for me.
 Hope you guys can help!

Comment: Your current rule doesn't *remove* `public`, it adds it

Comment: oh yes i see, thats needed to load the correct directory, but my question still stands, how can i remove the 'rijopleidingen' part after that rule has been executed?